# PHP equivalent of .Net Entity Framework

Tags: php, entity-framework

I like and I am so comfortable with EF provided by .Net wherein I can code first and database tables are generated by the framework itself etc. I am now coding a personal site using PHP. Is there any equivalent thing in PHP which will make my life easier. I cannot choose .Net for personal site. That answer is out :(.

Comment: Its ironic that the question that was closed as off-topic brought me "Notable Question" badge. Stackoverflow is so much like real world :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With "Code-First" approach, Doctrine:

Article: [Code First Approaching PHP with Doctrine 2.2.1 and Composer](https://web.archive.org/web/20160414091631/http://redgreenrefactor.blogsite.org:80/php/code-first-approaching-php-with-doctrine-2-2-1-and-composer).

Official Website: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html

You can check also other popular PHP ORMs, but I'm not sure if you could do "code-first approach" as Doctrine:

http://propelorm.org/

http://redbeanphp.com/

Comment: I Like Redbeanphp more. As there is no xml required. Thanks for the answer. I will accept the answer tomorrow. To see if I can get any other better answer.

Comment: Any idea about Model First  ?

Comment: Laravel also has a good ORM named Eloquent. But tou have to use Laravel Framework. You can see it's documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent