# PHP Entity Framework like .NET's

Tags: c#, php, entity-framework

I wanna know, if there's a Entity Framework for PHP, like the one for Microsoft (.NET), that treats the tables as Entities using LINQ for a better manipulation. I don't like to interact to the database directly by typing queries (SELECT * FROM...), I prefer more the LINQ method. Does exist a PHP framework with the decribed features?.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP equivalent of .Net Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643638/php-equivalent-of-net-entity-framework)

Comment: Thank you, but, I would like to read other answers too, regardless of what you said.

Comment: Unfortunately recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow, so your question will probably just be closed like the other one.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of good full featured PHP frameworks which has inbuilt entity frameworks.
1. CakePHP https://cakephp.org/
2. PhalconPHP https://phalconphp.com/en/
3. Laravel(Use Eloquent db abstraction layer inside) https://laravel.com/

Other than full featured frameworks, you can just the entity framework(db abstraction layer) also.

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent
2. https://www.doctrine-project.org/